# How to upload document and connect it to a SAP customer?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I would like to upload documents (e.g. PDF-documents) from a java application to SAP and connect the uploaded document with a customer.

Is there an function module for this purpose?

I already searched for a FM or some hints but found nothing concrete yet. I know that there is SAP ArchiveLink, but I have never worked with this technology before.

Hope someone could give me a starting point?

Best Regards

Markus

Answer (score 2):

A starting point: Generic Object Services, GOS for short. If you open XD03 for a debitor and use the little menu to upload an attachment, it's using GOS to store it.

The class CL_FITV_GOS contains all methods you need. Wrap those methods in function modules for your purpose.

Comment: I have two FM (by a user of SAP SCM) to figure out for this purpose: SCMS_HTTP_CREATE_FILES and ARCHIV_CONNECTION_INSERT

Comment: Those will not put the documents in the correct location, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SO_OBJECT_INSERT` together with `SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET` FMs like this:

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET'
    EXPORTING
      region    = 'B'
    IMPORTING
      folder_id = ls_fol_id
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS    = 1.

  ls_obj_data-objsns    = 'O'.
  ls_obj_data-objla     = sy-langu.
  ls_obj_data-objdes    = p_desc.
  ls_obj_data-file_ext  = 'PDF'.
  ls_obj_data-objlen    = LINES( it_content ) * 255.

  CALL FUNCTION 'SO_OBJECT_INSERT'
    EXPORTING
      folder_id             = ls_fol_id
      object_type           = 'EXT'
      object_hd_change      = ls_obj_data
    IMPORTING
      object_id             = ls_obj_id
    TABLES
      objhead               = it_objhead
      objcont               = it_content.
```

Both are remote-enabled and can be called like BAPIs. [Here is](http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/Smartforms/PO/Prg.htm) the full sample.